# Collecting and analysing data in RCT

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I am doing a research proposal. I am testing a new treatment combination in the experimental group and my control group only get placebo. I am planning to collect interval inferential data (blood test) and analysing it with T-test. Is T-testing the best way to analyse it? How can I justify why I chose this tool?

Comment: What do you mean by "interval inferential data"?

Comment: Do you mean Student's $t$ test (note lower case) or do you mean Hotelling's $T^2$ (note upper case).

Comment: If this is a real study on real people as opposed to self-study (see the tag http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info for details) then you seriously need to get help before you start experimenting on people.

Answer (score 1):

Given that randomized allocation ensures theoretical equipoise, you correctly chose a test not encompassing adjustment for confounders. However, if you are facing repeated measures (eg blood test results before and after intervention), I would recommend using a repeated-measure ANOVA, a generalized linear model, or generalized estimating equations.

Comment: Thank you. I looked the ANOVA test and looks very complicated... I have never done any statistic study I am on a medical course.

Comment: @gingergi Are you using R?